# Can not get table value after click on button using angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have one problem.I can not get table value in console after click on button using Angular.js .I am explaining my code below.

```
 <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" ng-click="exportData();">Export</button>
    </span>
<div class="table-responsive dashboard-demo-table"  id="exportable" style="display:none;">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">

       <thead>
       <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Product Name</th>
        <th>Discount</th>
        <th>Offer</th>
        <th>Unit Cost Price</th>
        <th>Unit Sale Price</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Shipping Charge</th>
        <th>Specification</th>
        <th>Display Sale price</th>
       </tr>
       </thead>

       <tbody>
       <tr   ng-repeat="rep in listOfReportData ">
        ----------------------------
       --------------------------------
       </tr>
       </tbody>

   </table>
</div>
```

When user is clicking on the `Export` button some array of data(`$scope.listOfReportData`) is displaying on the table. Chcek my controller code below.

```
 $scope.exportData=function(){
    $http({
            method:'POST',
            url:"php/getProductReportData.php",
            data:proData,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        }).then(function successCallback(response){
              $scope.listOfReportData=response.data;
                     console.log('export',document.getElementById('exportable').innerHTML);
        },function errorCallback(response) {
})
}
```

Here I am trying to check total table in console after data available there but it could not happen like that.I need to check  table  in console after table has full of data.Please help me.

Comment: Once you set the value to `scope` variable, it goes through digest cycle to bind elements in view and it definitely takes some time(in ms).

Comment: So Can i write console statement inside timeout function for result.

Comment: Try this: `$timeout(function(){ console.log(...) })`

Comment: Do you want to count the number of rows in the table?